# React Native - Share and re use components

Tags: android, reactjs, gradle, react-native

In order to maximize code re use, we are building a set of components that we want to use in multiple mobile apps. So far I have been able to do it using a git repository as dependency in my package.json.

I am using multiple native modules as dependencies in my main/core component module like so:

```
include ':react-native-navigation'
project(':react-native-navigation').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app')
include ':react-native-open-settings'
project(':react-native-open-settings').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-open-settings/android')
include ':react-native-localization'
project(':react-native-localization').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-localization/android')
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
```

Now, if I want to add a new native module into my core app, this requires that on every one of my child apps I need to update the build.gradle and settings.gradle, so the new modules also get compiled and added into the project.

I am looking into doing something like this in my settings.gradle child apps:

```
include ':core'
project(':core').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/core/android/app')
```

This seems to be the first step but this makes the core app compile fail because the "node_modules" folder is missing. Installing all the modules again inside the core module folder seems like an overkill.

My objective is to:

1. Have a core module that has both JS and Native Components
2. Create child apps that have this core as a dependency
3. Update core version without needing to manually update all the child apps, eventually removing manual steps leading to errors while building.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a private npm repository? You could put your all reusable components into a private npm repository, and then load them there for each app. Though I don't know if this can solve how to share the native modules.

Comment: I actually kind of already have a private repository. I mean, I use git to load the core module and it does work, however as you said, it does not load the native modules or dependencies so I have to compile and install on every child project.